# Problems when using DataTemplate in a UWP app (crashing, data not being set)

Tags: c++, xaml, data-binding, uwp

I'm getting my feet wet trying out Windows 10 UWP app development. I've installed Visual Studio 2015 and am currently playing around with trying to figure out how to work with data binding.

The following is my simple XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Pivot x:Name="docPivot"
           ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <PivotItem Header="{Binding Filename}">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Contents}"/>
                </PivotItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

This is my Mainpage.xaml.cpp in relevant part: (Document is a simple struct that just has two properties, a String Filename and a String Contents.)

```
MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    auto docs = ref new Vector<Document^>();
    auto doc1 = ref new Document();
    doc1->Filename = "Filename1";
    doc1->Contents = "Contents 1";
    docs->Append(doc1);
    auto doc2 = ref new Document();
    doc2->Filename = "Filename2";
    doc2->Contents = "Contents 2";
    docs->Append(doc2);
    docPivot->ItemsSource = docs;
}
```

However, I'm having a pair of issues I can't figure out:

The first is, instead of each PivotItem's header being `Filename`, they're both MyApp.Document, where MyApp is my namespace.

The second issue is, the TextBox is being properly populated with the contents from the data binding, and the two PivotItems can be switched between, but as soon as I try and select a Textbox, the app crashes with an access violation:

> Exception thrown at 0x0004CE1E in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Any input on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must add Bindable attribute to `Document` class.

```
[Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::Bindable]
public ref class Document sealed
```

And you must add

```
#include "Document.h"
```

in `Mainpage.xaml.h` file not the `.cpp` file. You Pivot's ItemTemplate should not contain PivotItem, you should do like this

```
<Grid>
<Pivot x:Name="docPivot">
    <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Filename}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Contents}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</Pivot>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I already had the first two covered, I should have mentioned those, but the updated XAML fixed both of my problems. Any idea why the incorrect approach I had been using worked partially but then would crash?

Comment: @WilliamJones It shouldn't crash just according to you provided code. May be some other code caused.